# Activating dynamic button

Tags: function, button, dynamic

I have created a dynamic button. and now I,m trying to add a dynamic anchor tag. But it doesn't work. Before posting this I went through all the other example, but no success. Please advice.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    //creating an dynamic button element
        var btn = document.createElement('input');
        var text = document.createTextNode('Click Me!')
        btn.appendChild(text);
        btn.id = "myBtn"
        btn.type = "button";
        btn.value="Click me!"
        document.body.appendChild(btn)

    //adding click event to the dynamic button
        $("body").on("click", "myBtn", function(){  
         var myLink = document.createElement('a')            
             var myText = document.createTextNode('This is a dynamic link')
             myLink.setAttribute("href", "http://www.example.com");
             myLink.target = "_blank"
             myLink.title = "www.example.com"
             myLink.style.marginTop = "25px"
             myLink.appendChild(myText);
             document.body.appendChild(myLink);

        })

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click','#myBtn',function(){

    //write your function here

});
```